# In Rally, when copying a test set, how do you copy the test case results with the test set?

Tags: testing, rally

I'm fairly new to Rally and so far have only used the web interface (I haven't used the Rally APIs from a programming languages yet).  Occasionally we have a test set that we don't finish in an iteration, so we'd like to be able to copy the test set to the next iteration but retain the test case results entered so far in the new iteration so that we don't have to look in 2 different places for the complete test set results.  Perhaps one solution is better iteration planning, but I'm still curious if there's a way to copy test case results along with a test set when copying a test set.

Answer (score 0):

Test Case Result cannot be copied. It can be created in UI or Web Services API with the identical data, but it does not support a copy functionality.

For a general example of how to create a TCR object using a browser REST client see this [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620056/rally-json-i-o-error-creating-a-test-case-result/18620170#18620170).

Here is a poof of concept app that creates a copy of an existing TCR. The app filters TestSets by Iteration, and loads those TestSets into a combobox. Based on the TestSet selection in the combobox another combobox is created, populated with TestCases. When a Test Case is selected from that combobox a grid is built with TestCaseResults. Doubleclicking on a TCR in the grid will invoke a copy function. See AppSDK2 topic on how to copy records [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/data_models). You may extend the code per your specifications. The source is in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/copy-tcr).

Minimally you need to change ObjectIDs of destination test case and destination test set in _copyRecordOnDoubleClick method below:

```
 Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'iteration',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select an Iteration:',
        labelWidth: 100,
        width: 300
    },


    onScopeChange: function() {
       if (this.down('#testSetComboxBox')) {
        this.down('#testSetComboxBox').destroy();
    }
    if (this.down('#testCaseComboxBox')) {
        this.down('#testCaseComboxBox').destroy();
    }
    if (this.down('#resultsGrid')) {
        this.down('#resultsGrid').destroy();
    }
    var testSetComboxBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox',{
        id: 'testSetComboxBox',
        storeConfig: {
        model: 'TestSet',
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()]
        },
        fieldLabel: 'select TestSet',
        listeners:{
                ready: function(combobox){
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
            this._onTestSetSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }
            else{
            console.log('selected iteration has no testsets');
            }
        },
                select: function(combobox){
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
            this._onTestSetSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }

                },
                scope: this
            }
    });
    this.add(testSetComboxBox);  
    },

     _onTestSetSelected:function(selectedTestset){
    var testCases = selectedTestset.getCollection('TestCases', {fetch: ['FormattedID','ObjectID', 'Results']});
    var ts  = {
            FormattedID: selectedTestset.get('FormattedID'),
            TestCaseCount: selectedTestset.get('TestCases').Count,
            TestCases: [],
            ResultCount: 0 
        };
    testCases.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success){
            Ext.Array.each(records, function(testcase){
            console.log("testcase.get('FormattedID')", testcase.get('FormattedID'));  
            console.log("testcase.get('Results').Count", testcase.get('Results').Count); 
            ts.ResultCount = testcase.get('Results').Count; 
            ts.TestCases.push({_ref: testcase.get('_ref'),
                FormattedID: testcase.get('FormattedID'),
                ObjectID: testcase.get('ObjectID')
                });
          }, this); 
          this._makeTestCaseCombobox(ts.TestCases);
        },
        scope: this
      });

    },

    _makeTestCaseCombobox:function(testcases){
    if (this.down('#testCaseComboxBox')) {
        this.down('#testCaseComboxBox').destroy();
    }
    if (this.down('#resultsGrid')) {
        this.down('#resultsGrid').destroy();
    }
        if (testcases.length>0) {
        var idArray = [];
        _.each(testcases, function(testcase){
            console.log(testcase);
            console.log('OID', testcase['ObjectID']);
            idArray.push(testcase['ObjectID']);
            });
        console.log('idArray',idArray);

        var filterArray = [];
        _.each(idArray, function(id){
            filterArray.push(
            {
            property: 'ObjectID',
            value:id
            }
            )
        });
         var filters = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', filterArray[0]);

         filterArray = _.rest(filterArray,1);  

         _.each(filterArray, function(filter){
            filters = filters.or(filter)
            },1);

         var testCaseComboxBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox',{
            id: 'testCaseComboxBox',
            storeConfig: {
            model: 'TestCase',
            pageSize: 100,
            autoLoad: true,
            filters:filters,
            fetch: true
            },
            fieldLabel: 'select TestCase',
            listeners:{
            ready: function(combobox){
                if (combobox.getRecord()) {
                this._onTestCaseSelected(combobox.getRecord());
                }
                else{
                console.log('selected testset has no testcases');
                }
            },
            select: function(combobox){
                if (combobox.getRecord()) {
                this._onTestCaseSelected(combobox.getRecord());
                }

            },
            scope: this
            }
        });
        this.add(testCaseComboxBox); 
        }
        else{
          console.log('selected testset has no testcases');
          }
    },

    _onTestCaseSelected:function(selectedTestcase){
      var results = selectedTestcase.getCollection('Results', {fetch: ['ObjectID','Date', 'TestSet', 'TestCase', 'Build', 'Verdict']});
      var tc  = {
            ObjectID: selectedTestcase.get('ObjectID'),
            FormattedID: selectedTestcase.get('FormattedID'),
            Results: [] 
        };
    results.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success){
            Ext.Array.each(records, function(result){
            console.log("result.get('ObjectID')", result.get('ObjectID'));  
            console.log("result.get('Verdict')", result.get('Verdict'));
            tc.Results.push({_ref: result.get('_ref'),
                ObjectID: result.get('ObjectID'),
                Date: result.get('Date'),
                Build: result.get('Build'),
                Verdict: result.get('Verdict')
                });
          }, this); 
          this._updateGrid(tc.Results);
        },
        scope: this
      });
    },

    _updateGrid: function(results){
         var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: results,
                pageSize: 100
            });
        if (!this.down('#resultsGrid')) {
        this._createGrid(store);
        }
        else{
        this.down('#resultsGrid').reconfigure(store);
        }
     },

  _createGrid: function(store){
        var that = this;
        var that = this;
        var resultsGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            id: 'resultsGrid',
            store: store,

            columnCfgs: [
            {
               text: 'ObjectID ID', dataIndex: 'ObjectID',
            },
            {
            text: 'Date', dataIndex: 'Date',
            },
            {
            text: 'Build', dataIndex: 'Build',
            },
            {
              text: 'Verdict', dataIndex: 'Verdict',
            },
            ],
             listeners: {
                celldblclick: function( grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex){
                that._copyRecordOnDoubleClick(record);     
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(resultsGrid);
     },

     _copyRecordOnDoubleClick: function(record){
      var that = this;
         console.log('record', record);
         Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                type: 'TestCaseResult',
                success: function(model) {  
                    that._model = model;
                    var copy = Ext.create(model, {
                        Date: record.get('Date'),
            Build: record.get('Build'),
            Verdict: record.get('Verdict'),
            TestCase: '/testcase/17237838118',
            TestSet: '/testset/17234968911'
                    });
                    copy.save({
                        callback: function(result, operation) {
                            if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                                console.log('result',result); 
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log("problem");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
     }  
 });
```

Comment: If test results can be created with the Web Services API, do you know of a script of some kind that can copy test results from one copy of a test set to another?