# Rally Defect.TestCaseResult is an invalid relationship

Tags: rally

I use pyral package to ingest test case results to Rally. Some of my test cases have User stories as work product and some have defects as the work product. While ingesting test case results to some test cases which have Defect as work product I get the following error

Rally Defect.TestCaseResult is an invalid relationship

```
rally = pyral.Rally object
response = rally.get('TestCase', fetch=True, query='FormattedID = "TCXXXX"', project="XXXXX")
tc = response.next()
rally.create('TestCaseResult', {'TestCase': tc._ref , 'Build': 'XXXXXXXX', 'Verdict': 'Pass', 'Notes': 'XXXXXX', 'Date': XXXXXX })

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyral/restapi.py", line 891, in put
 raise RallyRESTAPIError('%s %s' % (response.status_code, desc))
 pyral.restapi.RallyRESTAPIError: 422 Validation error: Defect.TestCaseResult is an invalid relationship
```

when I print the ref I do see tc object is test case object

```
print tc._ref
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/testcase/6337826741.js

print tc.ref
testcase/6337826741
```

Has anyone seen this? or know what the workaround is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen it, but here are a few steps to start troubleshooting:

Can you create a testcaseresult with pyral on a different testcase?

Can you create a testcaseresult with a browser REST client on the same testcase where it fails with pyral? If not, can you create a testcaseresult with the REST client on a different testcase? See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620056/rally-json-i-o-error-creating-a-test-case-result/18620170#18620170) for details on how to do it.

If the problem is specific to a testcase, is there a defect associated with that test case? Do you see any testcaseresult associated with this defect? (That would be strange)